# Google Scripts: Function to tally votes

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I am trying to create a simple Google spreadsheet function to convert a rank to a point system and then add the points.  A person (A,B,C,D) who has access to the spreadsheet will rank their choices (W, X, Y, Z) on a first choice (1), second choice (2), and third choice (3) basis.

The rows are the voters and the choices are in columns.

Each 1 vote = 3 points; 2 vote = 2 points; 3 vote = 1 point.

For some reason, my script is only outputting the length of the script and not the sum of the points.  Can you please help me identify where my script is going wrong?

```
function tally(rankarray) {
  var rank = 0;       // this is the vote cast
  var result = 0;     // this will hold the total
  var value = 0;      //  this holds the value of the vote cast

  for (var i=0; i < rankarray.length; i++){
    rank = rankarray[i];  
    if (rank = 1) {
    value = 3;
    }
    if (rank = 2) {
    value = 2;
    }
    if (rank = 3) {
    value = 1;
    }
    result += value;
  }

  return result;
}
```

Edit:

I think I fixed it.  Anyone see any issue with the below?

```
function tally(rankarray) {
  var rank = 0;
  var result = 0;     // this will hold the total
  var value = 0;      //  this holds the value of the vote cast

  for (var i=0; i < rankarray.length; i++){
    rank = rankarray[i];  
    if (rank == 1) {
      value = 3;
    }
    else if (rank == 2) {
      value = 2;
     }
    else if (rank == 3) {
      value = 1;
    }
    result += value;
    value = 0;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Please note that `if(rank = 1)` doesn't do what you think it does. The single equals sign tells it to assign the value `1` to the variable `rank`. You want a double equals sign: `if(rank == 1)`, which tells it to test whether or not the value of `rank` equals `1`. (Regardless, Nanashi's answer, which uses a `switch` construct instead of `if`, is a great solution in this case.)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following script:

```
function tally(rankarray) 
{
  var rank = 0;       // this is the vote cast
  var result = 0;     // this will hold the total
  var value = 0;      //  this holds the value of the vote cast

  for (var i=0; i < rankarray.length; i++)
  {
    rank = rankarray[i];
    switch(rank)
    {
        case 1:
            value = 3;
            break;
        case 2:
            value = 2;
            break;
        case 3:
            value = 1;
            break;
    }
    result += value;
  }
  return result;
}
```

[JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/CWscB/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks.  This returned a "0" regardless of the votes.  I think I figured out my problem though.  I chanced the if statements to elseif and also changed them to booleans if (rank ==1) etc.